# How to deserialize JSON data tree?

Tags: json, rest, silverlight-4.0

Suppose I have JSON data formatted as:(kind of tree data:)

{
"nodeData":
[
    "nodeObject":
    {
        "nodeName": "Node 1",

```
    "nodeChildren":
        [
            "nodeObject":
            {
            "nodeName": "Node 1-1"
            },
            "nodeObject":
            {
            "nodeName": "Node 1-2"

            },
            "nodeObject":
            {
            "nodeName": "Node 1-3",    
            "nodeChildren":
                [
                    "nodeObject":
                    {
                    "nodeName": "Node 1-3-1"        
                    }
                ]
            },

            "nodeObject":
            {
            "nodeName": "Node 1-4"

            },

            "nodeObject":
            {
            "nodeName": "Node 1-5",        
            }
        ]
},

"nodeObject":
{
"nodeName": "Node 2",
},

"nodeObject":
{
"nodeName": "Node 3",
}
```

]
}

in order deserialize this data, in SL app, I defined a internal class to match JSON data model like:

```
[DataContract]
internal class nodeObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string nodeName;     
    [DataMember]
    public nodeObject nodeChildren;
}
```

then use DataContractJsonSerializer to get data, but I got kind of error said:

Unexpected character encountered in JSON. Expected ',', got ':'. (37):

as data is kind of tree, List maybe not good for this kind of data?

How to resolve this issue?

---

Thanks, guys. If the json data is well formated, then I use following kind of code to deserializ the object for above data:

```
var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<nodeObject>));  
var nodes = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(e.Result) as List<nodeObject>;  
this.listBox1.ItemsSource = nodes;
```

But I still get null for nodes.

Not sure how to deserialize the object with this knid of tree data.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not valid javascript.  You can not define keys for array elements.  For instance, in the first line of your code:

```
 [ 
     "nodeObject":
         { "nodeName":
          //...
 ]
```

your code would need to be formatted like this:

```
[ {"nodeName": "Node-1-1"}, {"nodeName": "Node-1-2"} /* ... */ ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not valid JSON. I've reformatted it so it is

```
    {
    "nodeData": [
        "nodeObject",
        {
            "nodeName": "Node 1",
            "nodeChildren": [
                "nodeObject",
                {
                    "nodeName": "Node 1-1"
                },
                "nodeObject",
                {
                    "nodeName": "Node 1-2"
                },
                "nodeObject",
                {
                    "nodeName": "Node 1-3",
                    "nodeChildren": [
                        "nodeObject",
                        {
                            "nodeName": "Node 1-3-1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "nodeObject",
                {
                    "nodeName": "Node 1-4"
                },
                "nodeObject",
                {
                    "nodeName": "Node 1-5"
                }
            ]
        },
        "nodeObject",
        {
            "nodeName": "Node 2"
        },
        "nodeObject",
        {
            "nodeName": "Node 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Use [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your data.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that DataContractJsonSerializer only supports the following encodings: UTF-8, UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE. For this to work, you need to do something like:

```
                DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Client>));

                System.IO.MemoryStream clientListStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

                clientListStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result), 0, e.Result.Length);

                List<Client> Clients = json.ReadObject(clientListStream) as List<Client>;
                dgMain.ItemsSource = Clients;
```